# Can I "branch" VirtualBox snapshots (base multiple VM on the same disk image + separate diffs)?

Tags: images, virtualbox, snapshot

I keep multiple VirtualBoxes for different projects. They are all running the same Debian base system. Keeping complete copies of all the disk images is getting expensive.

Is there a way that I can base multiple VM on the same (read-only) disk image, with (hopefully small) diffs layered on top? This is just like snapshots work, except that there is no concept of "current" and "previous", they are more like branches.

Or can I just use snapshots (of the "same" VM) for this? I would be wanting to run more than one of those snapshots concurrently.

Comment: Yep, you can now: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#snapshots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of VirtualBox 3.1, this is possible. See http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-3.1; the branched snapshot capability is listed near the bottom of the page, under "VirtualBox 3.1.0".

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere I've read that this is an upcoming feature of VirtualBox for the next big update. To allow making Snapshots of Snapshots (and so branching it).

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible but keep in mind that VM's need to be Unique. you will need to make new SID's for the new branch.

Comment: "Make new SID's"? What does it mean?